# Javafx PieChart created with scene builder does not dispaly data

Tags: charts, javafx, builder, scene, pie-chart

Im having trouble using some of the Javafx examples from Oracle as the 'scenes' are not created with the Scene Builder so the code differs from what I want to use it for.

Im trying to create a layout with scenebuilder that holds a Pie Chart. I have set the fxid of the chart to 'myPieChart' with the corresponding `@FXML private Chart myPieChart;` at the start of my code.

I have also added the following code that gets executed on initialisation that I thought would have crated the chart:-

```
    ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new PieChart.Data("Grapefruit", 13),
            new PieChart.Data("Oranges", 25),
            new PieChart.Data("Plums", 10),
            new PieChart.Data("Pears", 22),
            new PieChart.Data("Apples", 30));


    PieChart myPieChart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
```

All of the values are being put into an observable list and then the Pie Chart is instantiated with the ObsevableList value.

Unfortunately my pie chart is not showing....what am I missing guys?

Cheers for any help.

Comment: If you still have issues after updating based on my answer, also post your fxml file and fxml loading code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a new PieChart.

The FXML loading process will create a chart instance for you and insert it as a child of the FXML defined layout Pane.  The @FXML annotation will inject a reference to the chart into your Controller.

All you need to do in your Controller's initializer is populate the existing chart with your data.  You can do this by calling [setData](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/PieChart.html#setData%28javafx.collections.ObservableList%29) on myPieChart.

Comment: Cheers mate! I also found that '@FXML private Chart myPieChart;' should have been '@FXML private PieChart myPieChart;' Once these changes were made all was well! Manyt hanks fella...now gotta try and figure out how to get the results from a resultSet into a TabelView :D

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this by just setting the id in fxml for your chart

```
public class GraphScreenController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    PieChart chart;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
 ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new PieChart.Data("Executed", 60),
            new PieChart.Data("Passed", 25),
            new PieChart.Data("Fails", 15));

 chart.setData(pieChartData);

}
}
```